# Restore Service Master Key w/Existing Encryption Data

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I recently implemented database encryption using Symmetric/Asymmetric keys and have the Database Master Key (DMK) encrypted by password.  Now if I'm understand the encryption hierarchy correctly, the DMK password will then be stored in the master database and is encrypted by the Service Master Key (SMK). My goal is to copy the database to another server to serve as a "test environment".  In order to do so, I'll need to restore a copy of the Service Master Key on the destination server in order to properly encrypt/decrypt the data.  I just want make sure that I'm reading the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187972.aspx) correctly regarding the RESTORE MASTER KEY command.  When I restore the SMK, any encrypted data on the destination server will first be decrypted by the current SMK and then re-encrypted using the new SMK.  Is it safe to assume that no other database should be adversely affected if they have encryption?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the syntax for [CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677241.aspx), the database master key (DMK) is encrypted by either a server-level certificate or a server-level asymmetric key. In order to restore that database on another server, the certificate or asymmetric key that protects the DMK needs to be present in the master database at the destination. Once you have that, you should be good to go.

If this is a cross-environment restore (e.g. prod → dev), I like to re-encrypt the key with an encryptor that doesn't exist at the source. It's a little added protection that ensures that the restore happens one way (i.e. you can't overwrite prod with dev).